# Pipe or sequence of function in python pandas or Filter then summarize (as dplyr)

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr, pipe

To contextualize. I'm an R heavy user, but currently switching between python (with pandas). Let's say I have this data frame

```
data = {'participant': ['p1','p1','p2','p3'],
        'metadata': ['congruent_1','congruent_2','incongruent_1','incongruent_2'],
        'reaction': [22000,25000,27000,35000]
        }

df_s1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['participant','metadata', 'reaction'])
df_s1 = df_s1.append([df_s1]*15,ignore_index=True)
df_s1
```

and I want to reproduce what I can easily do in R (pipe functions), by:

```
df_s1[(df_s1.metadata == "congruent_1") | (df_s1.metadata == "incongruent_1")].df_s1["reaction"].mean()
```

This is not possible. I just can success when I split this code into parts/variables:

```
x = df_s1[(df_s1.metadata == "congruent_1") | (df_s1.metadata == "incongruent_1")]
x = x["reaction"].mean()
x
```

In dplyr way, I'd go with

```
ds_s1 %>% 
  filter(metadata == "congruent_1" | metadata == "incongruent_1") %>% 
  summarise(mean(reaction))
```

Note: I highly appreciate concise references to a site in which I could transpose my R code to Python. Several literature is available, but with mixed formats and flexible styles.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have `.loc` here

```
df_s1.loc[(df_s1.metadata == "congruent_1") | (df_s1.metadata == "incongruent_1"), 'reaction'].mean()
Out[117]: 24500.0
```

Change to `isin` as Quang mentioned try to reduce the line of code

---

In base R

```
mean(ds_s1$reaction[ds_s1$metadata%in%c('congruent_1','incongruent_1')])
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain me why .loc is necessary? Thank you!

Comment: @Luis .loc is for slice both the column and index at the same time , in your case you pass the bool for index and want to select the column as well , so .loc is needed ~

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
df_s1.loc[(df_s1.metadata == "congruent_1") | (df_s1.metadata == "incongruent_1"), "reaction"].mean()
```

Or simpler with `isin`:

```
df_s1.loc[df_s1.metadata.isin(["congruent_1", "incongruent_1"]), "reaction"].mean()
```

Out:

```
24500.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Any chance to have a "pipe" flow such as tidyverse ?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other suggested solutions:

```
df_s1.query('metadata==["congruent_1","incongruent_1"]').agg({"reaction": "mean"})

 reaction    24500.0
 dtype: float64
```

Comment: thanks! It worked pretty well. I did not know the "agg"  function!!

Answer (score 1):

With [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) (I am the author) in python, it is easy for you to port your code from R to python:

```py
from datar.all import *

data = tibble(
  participant=['p1','p1','p2','p3'],
  metadata=['congruent_1','congruent_2','incongruent_1','incongruent_2'],
  reaction=[22000,25000,27000,35000]
)

df_s1 = data >> uncount(15)

df_s1 = df_s1 >> \
  filter((f.metadata == "congruent_1") | (f.metadata == "incongruent_1")) >> \
  group_by(f.metadata) >> \
  summarise(reaction_mean=mean(f.reaction))

print(df_s1)
```

Output:

```
        metadata  reaction_mean
0    congruent_1        22000.0
1  incongruent_1        27000.0
```

Comment: Really good to know!! Thanks for sharing this code!!!